# Kotlin: Access private var in test

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I have a Kotlin class containing the following property

```
private var items: List<Item> = listOf()
```

In my test I now want to check if there are items in the list. I try to do this with reflection:

```
val field = sut::class.members.findLast { f -> f.name.equals("items") }
```

I now get a KCallable<*> back but I don't know how I can access or at least count the items in my list.

Answer (score 1):

The `KCallable` you get is actually an instance of `KProperty1`, and you can call its `get` method to get the instance:

```
 val items = (field as KProperty1<ClassUnderTest, List<Item>>).get(sut)
```